# Minor ticks do not display properly

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, colorbar

With the following code, I get a colorbar with min value of 1 (0 value is transparent due to `mincnt=1` in the `hexbin()` method). Minor ticks are correctly displayed.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

# Create figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 2))

# Data
vals_x = np.random.standard_normal(10000)
vals_y = np.random.standard_normal(10000)

# Plot data
ax = plt.subplot(111)
h = ax.hexbin(vals_x, vals_y, gridsize=40, extent=(-2, 2,-2, 2), 
              mincnt=1, cmap=cm.viridis_r, edgecolors='k', lw=0.025)
ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)

# Show colorbar
axin = ax.inset_axes([0.02, 0.57, 0.03, 0.4])
cbar = plt.colorbar(h, cax=axin)
cbar.ax.tick_params(which='major', size=6, width=0.5)
cbar.ax.tick_params(which='minor', size=3, width=0.3)
ticks = cbar.get_ticks()
if False:
    ticks = np.insert(ticks, 0, 1) # add 1
cbar.set_ticks(ticks)
cbar.minorticks_on()
```

[image]

However, if I add "1" as a first major tick (by switching `False` to `True` in the code above), the minor ticks do not display properly anymore.
[image]

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing *MultipleLocator* with `from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator` and adding `cbar.ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(ticks[1]/5))` solves the problem. However, it does not explain it.